# How to update pivot table values automatically

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I have two separate tables `students` and `tutors`. I also have the pivot table `students_tutors` set up with two values `students_studentid` and `tutors_tutid`. In the flow of things, the client wants to assign tutors to students and vice versa, when adding them or by editing them later. So a student may have many tutors and a tutor may have many students. Now I want the pivot table values to be automatically updated when such a selection occurs. Multiple tutors/students may be assigned in one go. I am having difficulty with auto update on the pivot table. I am quite new to Laravel. Can anyone suggest how to go about it and what code to use and where to update pivot values and display in view.

My `add.blade.php` for students:

```
<select name="tutid" id="tutors" multiple>
    @foreach($tutors as $tutor)
        <option value="{{$tutor->tutid}}">{{$tutor->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

My `Student` model:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Student extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'studentid';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function Tutors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tutors::class);
    }

    public function Invoices()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Invoices::class);
    }
}
```

My `Tutor` model:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tutor extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $primaryKey = 'tutid';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function Students()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Students::class);
    }
}
```

My Student Controller `add()` method:

```php
public function add(Student $student, Tutor $tutor)
{
    $students = Student::all();

    $tutors = Tutor::all();

    return view('students.add', compact('students', 'tutors'));
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far ? I mean models and migrations.

Comment: Yes please, show some research effort :)

Comment: @louisfischer you may need to flag the question if you want to have https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17178443 approved because it seems that the comments you are referring are nowhere to find.

Comment: Along with my suggested edit I flagged the comments as "No longer needed". Those flags have been found helpful therefore the comments I was referring to were deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Here what you can do:
Loop through all the students IDs or Tutors IDs and assign them,
per example if we want assign multiple students to a tutor:

```
$tutor = Tutor::find($id);
foreach($students_id as $student_id){

    $tutor->students()->attach($student_id);

}
```

Note that you must have the relationship (students) inside ur tutor model:

```
public function students(){
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Student');
}
```

Do the same manipulation for the student!

Comment: Thank you @sletheren and everyone else. I had a nightmare pasting what I had done. Never mind that. With my values, it will take shape like this:`$tutor = Tutor::find($id);

foreach($studentid as $studentid){

    $tutor->students()->attach($studentid);`   However, where should I use this? In my store method in TutorsController?

Comment: The problem is, it looks like this right now. `public function store(Request $request)
      {

        $tutor = New tutors;
        $tutor->user_id = auth()->id();
        $tutor->studentid=request('studentid');
        $tutor->name = request('name');
        $tutor->contact = request('contact');
        $tutor->subjects = request('subjects');

        $tutor = Tutor::find($id);}`

Comment: Also, I am hoping to pick up multiple selected students/tutors and these are being picked from the relevant forms on respective add views. Will this work in that case?

Comment: Will I need to bring these values forward in an array? What will be the syntax in that case?

Comment: this yes, it depends on how u implemented it on the frontend, you can use multiselect and then it will automatically send an array to ur backend controller, then you apply the method I wrote for you above

Comment: Can't seem to get it. Can I get personalized help somewhere?